# How to count total height of all li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu in the footer of my page, it's content comes from database.

html:

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="">Foo</a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing...</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

js so far:

```
$('footer .submenu').each(function(i){
    $('footer .submenu:eq('+i+') a:first').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        elem = $('footer .submenu:eq('+i+') li').length;

        alert(elem);

    });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is, when I click in the first `<a />`, it returns me the total number of `<li>`. As the `<li>` are dynamically inserted, i don't know their `height` and I cant figure out a solution to that.
Can someone help me?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GwM5Q/2/

EDIT ---
I forgot to mention that the height of the `<ol>` is 0 and have css `overflow:hidden`. I updated the jsfiddle link, now it have CSS.

I'm trying to get the height to do an animation on click using `.animate()`. I only don't know how to get the `<li>` height.

Comment: why not just get the computed height of the `<ol>`? That'll be the height of all the `<li>` inside it.

Comment: If only you would have visited [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) and typed the word ***height*** into the search, you'd have found your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GwM5Q/1/).  I think this is what you're looking for as best as I can understand your question.  It gives the height of the parent li element that is clicked.  Please let me know if this is not the desired functionality.

```
       $("body").on("click", ".submenu a", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            elem = $(e.currentTarget).closest('li').height();

            alert(elem);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GwM5Q/27/)**

This is assuming you want the height of all `li`s. Just loop through them and sum their individual heights.

```
    $('footer .submenu').each(function(i){
        $('footer .submenu:eq('+i+') a:first').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var height = 0;
            $('footer .submenu:eq('+i+') li').each(function() {
                height += $(this).height();
            });

            alert(height);

        });
    });
```